# Influx Continuous Query - Is there any way to transform a filed data type from base table to the corresponding filed in down sampled table?

Tags: influxdb

Below is a continuous query -

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cq1 ON mydb 
BEGIN SELECT filed1 AS name
INTO cum_cq1 base_stats GROUP BY controller, time(1m) END
```

`filed1` is a floating value.

I want `name` to be an integer or long.

Is there any way for this transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, InfluxDB supports following types of data: string, integer, float, boolean. No long type.
There are two options in my opinion to achieve integer type in your case.

1. Use ceil() function:

   ```
   CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cq1 ON mydb  
   BEGIN SELECT ceil(filed1) AS name  
   INTO cum_cq1 base_stats GROUP BY controller, time(1m) END
   ```

This will round your float value to nearest integer.
[Ceil function docs for InfluxQL](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#ceil)

2. Use "::integer" operator to cast value to integer:

   ```
   CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cq1 ON mydb  
   BEGIN SELECT filed1::integer AS name  
   INTO cum_cq1 base_stats GROUP BY controller, time(1m) END
   ```

This will round down your integer.

[Cast operation docs for InfluxQL](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-data/#cast-operations)